# Как переопределить переменную (PHP)

Tags: php

В header.php есть переменная $title которая определяется там же (в зависимости от URL страниц).
В одной из внутренних страниц я хочу переопределить $title, так как он берется там из БД.
Например: в header.php есть if (...) {$title = "Раздел 1";} а потом echo $title

А в inner.php -

include(header.php);
...
SELECT .....

**$title = "Страница 1";**

И вот это, разумеется, не работает. Пытался использовать global, но без успеха. Как нужно переписать из inner.php переменную $title (из header.php)? Спасибо за советы, я не очень в PHP разбираюсь...

Comment: покажите строку из header, как получается $title

Comment: $Title = $art['ArticleTitle']." | ".$art['ArtCatName'];
<title><?=$title?></title>

Comment: или так:

if (stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'page2') == true) { $Title  = "стр 2" } 
а потом <title><?=$title?></title>

Comment: @Sol вы сначала выводите $tile, а потом хотите его поменять? Так не получится. Вам надо сначала подготовить все данные для вывода, потом выводить один раз, тогда всё станет гораздо проще.

Comment: Я понимаю, везде он или строится до вывода в зависимости от названия страницы, или берется из БД. Но есть одна страница, где он в ней самой высчитывается , поэтому там приходится делать "заплатку".

Comment: определяйте до include а там проверяйте, если не empty - задайте значение, а так - оставляйте какое есть. включенный файл видит переменные внешнего

Comment: так не могу же - он определяется только внутри
 да, включенный файл видит переменные внешнего , а мне надо наоборот, чтобы внешний  файл видит переменные внутреннего

Comment: а что у вас title выводится не в header.php?

Comment: выводится разумеется в  header.php, но есть одна страница, где по определенным причинам я "вытаскиваю" title из самого текста, который находится в ней  ниже  header

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет рефакторинг. Надо исправить архитектуру вашего приложения так, чтобы весь код работал как раньше, а в inner.php вы могли реализовать новый правильный подход.

1. Перенесите логику вычисления title из header.php в функцию `clalcHeader`:

```php
<?php // helpers.php

function clalcHeader(): array {
    $title = 'default';
    if (stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'page2') == true) {
         $title = 'стр 2';
    }

    // ...

    return [
        'title' => $title,
        // ...
    ];
}
```

2. Перенесите логику вывода title в функцию `printHeader`:

```php
<?php // helpers.php

function printHeader(array $header): void {
    // ...

    printf('<title>%s</title>', htmlspecialchars($header['title']));

    // ...
}
```

2. Используйте `clalcHeader` и `printHeader` в `header.php`

```php
<?php // header.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/helpers.php';

$header = clalcHeader();
printHeader($header);
```

После этого весь ваш код будет работать так же как и прежде.

3. Теперь в inner.php не подключайте header.php, вместо этого используйте `clalcHeader` и `printHeader`:

```php
<?php // inner.php

require_once __DIR__ . '/helpers.php';

$header = clalcHeader();
$header['title'] = 'Страница 1'; // перезапишите title в соответствии с логикой inner.php
printHeader($header);
```

Когда справитесь с этой задачей, подумайте о переходе на архитектуру, в который вывод у вас будет только один раз в самом конце. То есть у вас будет объект (или массив, если вы ещё не разобрались с ООП) `Page`, который содержит title, styles, scripts, content и прочее. Этот объект будет постепенно заполняться и выводится уже в самом конце.

Comment: Спасибо! Вышло!